# What is this variable kind of thing in css?

Tags: css

I just discovered something in css, forwhat I can not find any explanations in google. I'm pretty bad with css, so I hope you can explain this to me.

```
outline-color: Highlight
```

I mean the 'Highlight'. My struggle is, I never declared this in any way and I never heard of it neither. If I use it, it is just a blueish color.

Is this any kind of system-specific variable? Are there any other things like this?

Comment: Pretty sure because it doesnt recognise the word Highlight that its setting it to the default blue

Comment: That is just a keyword, one of the now deprecated "system colors". See, e.g., https://www.quackit.com/css/color/values/css_system_colors.cfm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Highlight` is indeed a system color keyword, documented in [section 18.2 of CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/ui.html#system-colors) and [section 4.5.1 of css-color-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#css2-system). It does vary depending on the OS or platform displaying this color. It is *not* the same thing as a custom property (or CSS variable) — custom property names begin with `--` and are referenced using `var()`. It's much more akin to things like `red`, `green` and `blue`, also predefined colors, but not system colors.

The description is very brief but should give you a rough idea of what it represents (assuming the name "Highlight" doesn't already!):

> **Highlight**
>   Item(s) selected in a control.

In any case, system colors are deprecated and should not be used in public sites.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have predefined color, the usual are `red`, `yellow`, `coral` or something like this, but they also have colornames for colors, which are part of the design scheme of the specific browser. For example `buttonface` is the greyish color of buttons in Chrome. So to keep safe always use the usual colors, because the OS/Browser specific ones could always change.

Comment: And they are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight is a predefined color in css which the browser will recognise, much like your standard red, blue etc....

If you play around in devtools on chrome or another inspector you can see all these colors.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the selection color, here is the css code:

```
::-moz-selection {
  background: #ccc;
}
::selection {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Note that the moz prefix is for firefox. You can replace `#ccc` with your color.
However if you're talking about using variables in css, try [sass](https://sass-lang.com)